# Setting up QtCreator cross compiler for ARM on Windows

Tags: windows, qt, arm, cross-compiling, yagarto

I need to develop Qt and command line software for the BeagleBone Black and Raspberry Pi-2. Ideally I wish to use QtCreator as I am accustomed to it, but in any case I need to use QtDesigner for GUI work.

I have spent days trawling through articles, going around in circles and getting nowhere.

The Raspberry Pi-2 has Raspbian/Jessie installed together with Qt 5.2.3. I can design, compile and run Qt desktop applications on this. Of course compilation is slow and not really usable for development work.

To try and keep matters simple, I downloaded qt-opensource-windows-x86-android-5.3.2.exe and installed that on my Windows 7 (64-bit) system. My belief is that this Qt install is the same version as the Qt on the Pi-2 and already contains the ARM7 library files required for cross-compiling. All that should be needed is a cross-compiler for Windows/ARM?

Windows/QtCreator complained in Tools > Options > Qt Versions about the Qt 5.3 for Android armv7 stating "No compiler can produce code for this Qt version...".

For a Windows/ARM cross-compiler I downloaded and installed Yagarto (yagarto-bu-2.23.1_gcc-4.7.2-c-c++_nl-1.20.0_gdb-7.5.1_eabi_20121222.exe). I figured I then just need to set the QtCreator compiler path in Tools > Options > Compilers and then things would start working. This is not the case.

Clearly I am missing something important and have managed to become confused by the number of not-quite-relevant articles I have read.

Is Yagarto the cross-compiler I need in this situation?

How do I define the compiler in QtCreator and get rid of the error?

Is there an easier way to set-up this stuff?

Thank you.

Details:
QtCreator 3.2.1 (Qt 5.3.2)
Windows 7 64-bit service pack 1

Edit:

I have just tried again using the GCC ARM Embedded ToolChain and GNU Make for Windows. The result is the same in that I cannot seem to configure the settings for QtCreator ARM7 and make it happy.